# Why am I getting a cors error even after setting up a proxy server using cors?

Tags: get, cors

i'm trying to use the riotGames api for a projects and I keep getting cors error. Here is my code

Server

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const axios = require('axios')
// const { response } = require('express')



app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
}));

const API_KEY = "not gonna leak my key lol"

function getPlayerUUID(playerName) {
    return axios.get("https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/" + playerName + "?api_key=" + API_KEY)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        return response.data.puuid
    }).catch (err => err)
}

app.get('/past5games', async (req,res) =>{
    const playerName = "YouGotCrit"
    //PUUID
    const PUUID = await getPlayerUUID(playerName)
    const API_CALL = "https://americas.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/by-puuid/" + PUUID + "?api_key=" + API_KEY

    const gameIDs = await  axios.get(API_CALL)
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(err=>err)

    var matchDataArray = []

    for (var i = 0; i<gameIDs.length - 15; i++){
        const matchId = gameIDs[i]
        const matchData = await axios.get("https://americas.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/" + PUUID + "?api_key=" + API_KEY)
        .then (response => response.data)
        .catch(err=>err)
        matchDataArray.push(matchData)
    }
    res.json(matchDataArray)
})

app.listen(4000, function () {
    console.log("Server started on port 4000")
})
```

index.js

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Home() {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("")
  const [gameList, setGameList] = useState({})

  function getPlayerGames(event){
    axios.get("http://localhost/4000/past5games/")
    .then(function(response){
      setGameList(response.data)
    })
    .catch(err=>err)
  }

  console.log(gameList)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <input type="text" onChange={e => setSearchText(e.target.value)}></input>
      <button onClick={getPlayerGames}>Get match history</button>
      { gameList.length !== 0 }
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've tried following multiple videos and looking online but its the same solution everytime which wont work for me. The video where I got my code from it worked perfectly for him but I keep getting this error.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wsZE.png)

Answer (score 1):

So apparently there is a bug in axios' get function which is fixed by adding "{headers: {
'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}}" to the get request

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5296#issuecomment-1326548416

full ex:
axios2.get("https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/" + playerName +"?api_key=" + API_KEY, {headers: {
'Accept-Encoding': 'identity',
}})
.then(response => {
console.log(response)
return response.data.puuid
}).catch(err=>console.log(err))