# Why Cors is blocking me even if I allow it on the server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors

I built a React App, deployed to heroku added a domain and it is secured. Every request is made from https and every time it is supposed to retrieve something from the server I get

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '******' from origin '******' has been
> blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource.

In my React app I have a file called setupProxy which contains

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: '******',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

and all my calls are made by using Axios

```js
  const API = axios.create({baseURL:'https://tldb-server.herokuapp.com'});
  API.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
    if(localStorage.getItem('profile')) {
        req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile')).data.token}`
    }
    return req;
    
})
```

My index.js file on the server-side is just this:

```js
import cors from 'cors'
app.use(cors())
```

before any routes declared.
If you guys have any ideas why I get this, because I can't figure it out. Thank you

> I looked up in my server logs and I found this:
> 2023-04-14T22:44:34.262800+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start
> 2023-04-14T22:44:34.262801+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
> 2023-04-14T22:44:34.262801+00:00 app[web.1]:
> 2023-04-14T22:44:35.148069+00:00 app[web.1]: connected to the database
> 2023-04-14T22:44:35.152857+00:00 app[web.1]: Server Running on Port
> 47860 2023-04-14T22:44:35.392826+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
> from starting to up 2023-04-14T22:45:25.017934+00:00 app[web.1]:
> 2023-04-14T22:45:25.017962+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- Last few GCs --->
> 2023-04-14T22:45:25.017962+00:00 app[web.1]:
> 2023-04-14T22:45:25.017971+00:00 app[web.1]: [20:0x62c61e0]    50303
> ms: Scavenge 186.5 (201.5) -> 186.5 (202.2) MB, 0.5 / 0.0 ms  (average
> mu = 0.982, current mu = 0.975) allocation failure;
> 2023-04-14T22:45:25.017972+00:00 app[web.1]: [20:0x62c61e0]    50714
> ms: Mark-sweep 276.3 (291.8) -> 273.7 (291.5) MB, 4.3 / 0.0 ms  (+ 2.3
> ms in 139 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.2 ms, walltime
> since start of marking 442 ms) (average mu = 0.986, current mu =
> 0.989) finalize increment 2023-04-14T22:45:25.017972+00:00 app[web.1]:  2023-04-14T22:45:25.017972+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- JS stacktrace --->
> 2023-04-14T22:45:25.017972+00:00 app[web.1]:
> 2023-04-14T22:45:25.017976+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: Reached heap
> limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
> 2023-04-14T22:45:25.018537+00:00 app[web.1]:  1: 0xb7b3e0
> node::Abort() [node] 2023-04-14T22:45:25.018937+00:00 app[web.1]:  2:
> 0xa8c8aa  [node] 2023-04-14T22:45:25.019395+00:00 app[web.1]:  3:
> 0xd69100 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
> const*, bool) [node] 2023-04-14T22:45:25.019848+00:00 app[web.1]:  4:
> 0xd694a7
> v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
> const*, bool) [node] 2023-04-14T22:45:25.020359+00:00 app[web.1]:  5:
> 0xf46ba5  [node] 2023-04-14T22:45:25.020892+00:00 app[web.1]:  6:
> 0xf5908d
> v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace,
> v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
> 2023-04-14T22:45:25.021414+00:00 app[web.1]:  7: 0xf5bff5
> v8::internal::Heap::HandleGCRequest() [node]
> 2023-04-14T22:45:25.021912+00:00 app[web.1]:  8: 0xeda14f
> v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts() [node]
> 2023-04-14T22:45:25.022509+00:00 app[web.1]:  9: 0x12da5f5
> v8::internal::Runtime_StackGuard(int, unsigned long*,
> v8::internal::Isolate*) [node] 2023-04-14T22:45:25.023186+00:00
> app[web.1]: 10: 0x1707b79  [node] 2023-04-14T22:45:25.040222+00:00
> app[web.1]: Aborted 2023-04-14T22:45:25.042479+00:00 app[web.1]: npm
> notice  2023-04-14T22:45:25.042544+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice New
> minor version of npm available! 9.5.0 -> 9.6.4
> 2023-04-14T22:45:25.042729+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice Changelog:
> https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.6.4
> 2023-04-14T22:45:25.042767+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.6.4` to update! 2023-04-14T22:45:25.042880+00:00
> app[web.1]: npm notice  2023-04-14T22:45:25.165762+00:00
> heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 134

I don't know what Heap Reallocation memory means..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74579418/215552

Comment: Your node application is running out memory. This is not normal. Hard to tell what would cause this just based on the code that was shared.